# How do I move the blocks to the next column?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: How do I make these blocks] go into the next column once I add more of them?

GS0 is the background GS0 is a background class and block is the class of the block.

```
 .GS0{
    min-height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    

}
.block{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 2px solid ;
    border-color: rgb(255, 175, 2);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please also provide your HTML. CSS code lines without corresponding HTML is useless for others to reproduce and then solve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

on the parent div *(or whatever container element was used)*.

Note that `flex-wrap: nowrap` is the default value.